# Are there any webpage that provide free master pages for download?

Tags: master-page, custom-masterpage

Are there websites that have master pages template for designers to download and modify?

I notice that there are 2 type of master page templates as follows:
[1] template that require to be installed on the web server extensions\12\template\ location.
[2] template that is plain vanilla. (a single *.master file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=sharepoint%20masterpage&ac=1). There are many things there to enhance SharePoint.

http://sharepoint2010html5.codeplex.com/

http://sp2010metro.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for the SharePoint 2010 Masterpage. Strange, I search CodePlex using the term `SharePoint 2007 MasterPage Templates` but could not find any SharePoint 2007 MasterPage. Do you have any good website recommendation that include SharePoint 2007?

Comment: There are a number of resources on the web that show you how to build custom master pages for WSS 3.0. I find it odd there is nothing on CodePlex as well. Do you want to re-tag your question with the SharePoint version?

Comment: Actually, I am looking for both SharePoint 2007 as well as SharePoint 2010. To me, I think that the master page was not a good feature as there are many problems and obstacles that need to overcome before getting the design that you want and can also work nicely with your aspx files.

Comment: True! I'm lucky my users are pretty happy with the default 2010 design...

Comment: Thats good. But I prefer that the master page can work like the PowerPoint 2000 Slide Master. Simple and not so problematic.